# Get count of rows since the past 7 days

Tags: mysql, count, google-bigquery, timestamp

I am trying to set up a MySQL query get metrics of the number of rows added since the past 7 days from the MySQL database. (Using BigQuery)

For simplicity, let's assume that there are only 2 fields: `id` and `createdDate`.

Here's what I have tried that did not work:

```
select count(*) from my_table where createdDate >= TIMESTAMP_SUB(createdDate, INTERVAL 7 DAY);
```

Bigquery is not letting me create variable that I could use as `NOW()` and when I try `TIMESTAMP_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)`, it does not work.

Any other ideas on how to get the count of the rows created since the past 7 days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In BigQuery you should use CURRENT_DATE() or CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() depends on context

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This is the error I get when I use `CURRENT_DATE()`: `No matching signature for function TIMESTAMP_SUB for argument types: DATE, INTERVAL INT64 DATE_TIME_PART. Supported signature: TIMESTAMP_SUB(TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL INT64 DATE_TIME_PART) at [1:79]
`

Comment: so, you should use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` then